# User Profile Access in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, profile-sync

Can anybody tell me in which scenario User Profile Access is maintained in SharePoint even though profile is deleted/disable from Active Directory and We ran Incremental Synch followed by My_Site_CleanUp job .

Comment: Which version of SharePoint? SP2010? SP 2013? Online?

Comment: SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it happens when user profile service application  "Profile Synchronization Status" is stuck in synchronizing state.

**If Account is removed in AD but User Profile still exist
You can perform the following to resolve the issues:**

- Make sure User Profile Synchronization service is running
  In the user profile service application make sure "Profile Synchronization Status" is not stuck in synchronizing state.
- Start a full User Profile Synchronization
  Re-add forest and make sure the password of the account used for synchronization isn't expired